# Use function signature as typing for callable parameter in mypy

Tags: typing, mypy

If I have a function like this, that takes a callable:

```
def some_func(my_func: Callable[[int, str], None], x: int, y: str) -> None:
    my_func(x, y)
```

And I have the callable function I plan to pass in with all its type hints:

```
def the_function(x: int, y: str) -> None:
    # do something
    return None
```

It's a bit silly that the callable's signature in both functions is the same. Is it possible to abstract it out into a variable, so you have something like:

```
SigType = Callable[[int, str], None]

def some_func(my_func: SigType, x: int, y: str) -> None:
    pass

# I'm sure this won't work, but you know what I mean, I hope
def the_function(**SigType) -> None
    pass
```

Even [the example in the docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#callable-types-and-lambdas) has this weird redundancy in typing, so curious if it's been tackled.

Comment: I don't think this exists, because what would be the variable names you could then use if you do something like `**SigType`?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know, but it feels very redundant as it is and seems like you should be able to define a function signature and pop it into various places.

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/. Not directly applicable to your scenario, but allows you to use inferred parts of the signature (`P.args` and `P.kwargs`) throughout rest of function.

Comment: If you don't care about `x` and `y` specifically, and just want to forward them to `some_func` (in other words taking `*args` and `**kwargs`) then that's where `ParamSpec` comes in.